# Подсветка активного пункта меню при разных get параметрах в Yii2 Navbar

Tags: yii2, yii-bootstrap

Использую Navbar в Yii, генерирую для него в цикле несколько ссылок с параметром:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $names[$i]; $i++) {
     $labels[]= ['label' => $i, 'url' => Url::toRoute(['/site/index', 'id' => $i])];         
}
```

Меню строится, но при переходе по ссылкам с разными параметрами эти ссылки не подсвечиваются как активные. Активным остается ссылка home, соответствующая /site/index .

Я предположил, что связано это с тем, что я использовал Url::toRoute, вместо обычного

```
'url' => ['маршрут']
```

Однако, я не нашел в документации, как в этой нотации записывать параметры. Также я не нашел там внятного описания управления активностью ссылки:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В NavBar виджет задать параметр в ссылке можно следующим образом:

```
'url' => [ '/site/index', 'id' => $id ]
```

И да, с такой записью подсветка активной ссылки будет работать.